# .indexOf() not working with specific vowel

Tags: javascript, algorithm

So I'm making an algorithm that converts input to Pig Latin. Here's what I have so far:

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {
    var consonantCluster = [];
    var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    var stringArray = str.split('');

    if (vowels.indexOf(stringArray[0]) === 0) {
        stringArray.push('w', 'a', 'y');
        stringArray = stringArray.join('');
        console.log(stringArray);
        return stringArray;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
        if (vowels.indexOf(stringArray[i]) == -1) {
            consonantCluster.push(stringArray[i]);
            stringArray.push(stringArray[i]);
        } else {
            stringArray.push('a', 'y');
            stringArray.splice(0, consonantCluster.length);
            stringArray = stringArray.join('');
            console.log(stringArray);
            return stringArray;
        }
    }

    return str;
}
translatePigLatin("eight");
```

It works for the most part. However, when I hand a word to the function that's a vowel, it doesn't work if it doesn't begin with the letter A. Instead it returns `ay` as opposed to what it should return if the word starts with a vowel `way`. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `vowels.indexOf(stringArray[0]) === 0` is only true when the first character of `str` is `a`.  The `.indexOf()` function returns the index where a match is found, and that comparison only succeeds when the index is zero - where the `a` is located.

Comment: What is Pig Latin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote line 6 you were only checking to see if the first letter of stringArray was equal to the first value of the vowels array (index = 0).

If you change `(vowels.indexOf(stringArray[0]) === 0)` to `if (vowels.indexOf(stringArray[0]) !== -1) {` you will be checking to see if the first letter in the stringArray matches any of the values in the vowels array.

Comment: Thank you this answer helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

[W3 Schools answers your question](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

## The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.

### This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.

#### Note: The indexOf() method is case sensitive.

#### Return Value:    A Number, representing the position where the specified searchvalue occurs for the first time, or -1 if it never occurs**